# regex to get value from string

Tags: c#, regex

Im trying to get value from string `1-1:0.0.0(123123)`
Here is code

```
string str = "\r\n1-1:0.0.0(123123)\r\n";
string patt = @"1-1:0.0.0(\(.*?)\)\s";
Match match = Regex.Match(str, patt,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
string v = match.Groups[1].Value;
```

problem is that i dont get clear value = `"(123123"`
can someone explain why there is round bracket at beginning ? :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The escaping of the parenthesis is not correct.

Change your pattern to the following (note that the backslash is in front of the first opening `(`):

```
@"1-1:0.0.0\((.*?)\)\s";
```

Answer (score 3):

Your opening-round-bracket match `\(` is *inside* the start of your capture group `(`.

Replace `(\(` with `\((`.

Also replace `0.0.0` with `0\.0\.0` for good measure.

Answer (score 2):

Your escape character `(\(` is misplaced:

Please try following

```
string str = "\r\n1-1:0.0.0(123123)\r\n";
string patt = @"1-1:0.0.0\((.*?)\)\s";
Match match = Regex.Match(str, patt, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
string v = match.Groups[1].Value;
```

This will print

```
123123
```

Answer (score 1):

Your capturing group is `(\(.*?)`, that is a pair of parentheses which creates the capturing group, with a content of `\(.*?` - matching a literal opening parenthesis and a non-greedy sequence of any characters.

Also note that the `.` characters in your pattern are not matching literal dots, but any character, I point this out since the target string seems to contain dots.